# jQuery ui sortable and draggable with overlapping containers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have multiple sortables, which can overlap each other. Sortables are connected to each other and allowed to drag an element to another. Also there are other items, which can be dragged into these sortables.

I had a tricky part, when a placeholder is fully over another placeholder. This prevented me to drop an element from an outer container to the inner container. I have extended the sortable widget and modified a little bit to check the z-indexes instead of the containment.

```
if (innermostContainer && $.contains(this.containers[i].element[0],innermostContainer.element[0])){
```

changed to:

```
if (innermostContainer && parseInt(this.containers[i].element.css('zIndex')) < parseInt(innermostContainer.element.css('zIndex'))){
```

It works well for this problem.

Next problem is that if I drag and drop an item from the draggables into the inner container, 2 placeholder appears and tries to add them both with error.

(If my previous z-index fix isn't applied, the dragged item added to the inner container and also the other container too) So mainly my fix put the outer container item into the inner container.

Both effects are bad for me, but I would like to fix this by adding only one placeholder and only one item.

Do you have any solution what should I do?

I have created an example to show you the problem: http://jsbin.com/irigas/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took lot of hours, but I was able to figure out a solution, which I will share for a possible solution.

I have created a dummy sortable, which will get the unwanted items on drag.

```
var dummy = $('#dummy');
  dummy.testSortable({
   items: '.item', 
   helper: "clone",
   tolerance: "pointer",
   appendTo: 'body'
  });
  window.dummySortable = dummy.data('sortable'); //this data key depends on the actual jQuery ui version
```

Also we need to mark the drag start and end events globally, because we need to check it later:

```
start: function() {
    window.isdrag = true;

},
stop: function() {
    window.isdrag = false;
}
```

Then in the previously extended method we need to add this:

```
if (innermostContainer && parseInt(this.containers[i].element.css('zIndex')) < parseInt(innermostContainer.element.css('zIndex'))) {
    if(window.isdrag){
        innermostContainer = window.dummySortable;
        innermostIndex = this.containers.indexOf(innermostContainer);
    }
    continue;
}
```

This will filter any unwanted element on drag and send them into the dummy sortable. You can see that green background in the back, that is the dummy sortable.

Test revision #2 with solution: http://jsbin.com/irigas/2/

If you have any toughs about this hacky solution, feel free to share as I'm curious if we could make this better.